# How to output counts for list of active/inactive inputs?

Tags: arrays, linux, if-statement, awk

I have this input file (1=active, 0=inactive)

```
a  1
a  0                    
b  1                      
b  1
b  0
c  0 
c  0
c  0
c  0
.
.
.
```

And want output like this:

```
 X       repeats            active count    inactive count
 a       2 times                 1               1 
 b       3 times                 2               1 
 c       4 times                 0               4
```

I tried:

```
awk -F "," '{if ($2==1) a[$1]++; } END { for (i in a); print i, a[i] }'file name
```

But that did not work.
How can I get the output?

Comment: show some code you tried and it didn't work. Also please rewrite your question as it's very hard to understand

Comment: awk -F "," '{if ($2==1) 
a[$1]++;
}
END {
for (i in a);
print  i, a[i] 
}'file name   this cod but it it didnt work as i want

Comment: i want to give me output that desplay how many times the letter a or b or c appears and from this result i want to know which is active and inactive  hope to be clear for you  pls notic that is a sample of big file

Comment: I have edited your question. Notice the changes so that you write better questions next time. Especially: All essential information should be in the question, not in comments.

Comment: Jan Doggen  thank you for give me the information coz this is the first time that i ask ques. in  this site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to give you an idea this awk should work:

```
awk '$2{a[$1]++; next} {b[$1]++; if (!($1 in a)) a[$1]=0} END{for (i in a) print i, a[i], b[i], (a[i]+b[i])}' file
a 1 1 2
b 2 1 3
c 0 4 4
```

You can format the output way you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
awk -f r.awk input.txt
```

where `input.awk` is your data file, and `r.awk` is

```
{
    X[$1]++
    if ($2) a[$1]++
    else ia[$1]++
}
END {
    printf "X\tRepeat\tActive\tInactive\n"
    for (i in X) {
        printf "%s\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", i, X[i], a[i], ia[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much its work exactlly like i want and im agine agreatfull for all

Answer (score 1):

#### This is GNU [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
awk '{a[$1]++; if ($2!=0) {b[$1]++;c[$1]+=0} else {c[$1]++;b[$1]+=0}}END {for (i in a) print i, a[i], b[i], c[i]}' file
```

Comment: Can you tell me what this is `gnu awk`, and not work with other `awk`

Comment: @Jotne GNU awk is foremost in Windows environment.

Comment: @captcha Here you are very wrong.  Many linux distro uses `gnu awk` like all `ubuntu` version. You do not see this, since you type `awk` and this points to file `gawk`.  Type `awk --version` and you see example like this `GNU Awk 3.1.8`  And with more than 3000 points here, you should know this.

Comment: @Jotne sorry, I don't understand, what you mean. I'm on Windows, and there we haven't other `awk`s than GNU.

Comment: Ok, if you use function that only exists in some version like using multiple characters in `RS` (record selector), its normal to write that this only works in `gnu awk`.  But you are not using any special function, sou you could write `This is an awk solution`, no need to say its `gnu`.  Your solution are portable cross any version, not only `gnu`.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another simple way to do it with `awk`

```
awk '{a[$1]++;b[$1]+=$2} END { for (i in a) print i,a[i],b[i],a[i]-b[i]}' file
a 2 1 1
b 3 2 1
c 4 0 4
```

No test is needed, just sum the column $2 and this gives number of hits.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
{ repeats[$1]++; counts[$1,$2]++ }
END {
    for (key in repeats)
        print key, repeats[key], counts[key,1]+0, counts[key,0]+0
}
' file
```